# Making netbeans skip java class files when compiling.

Tags: java, netbeans

So I'm working on a java code in netbeans and I have some classes that are pretty buggy and I was wondering how to tell netbeans to "not compile" those classes so that I can compile my program without debugging them? I'm not using the classes in any part of the code, netbeans just trying to compile them automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqExcludes you will find your answer.

Feature for `NetBeans 6.0` permitting include and exclude lists to be configured for project source roots

- Goto Project Properties
- Select the "Sources" node in the left hand tree
- Click on Include/Excludes in the lower left corner
- Specify which files to exclude in the lower input field.